# Magento 2 - custom model save triggers error - Fatal error: Call to a member function dispatch() on a non-object

Tags: magento2

I am creating a simple frontend magento 2 module to take input from user and save output in database.

Here is what i have tried.

Index.php -- (Index controller index action)

```
namespace Companyname\Faq\Controller;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request) {
        return parent::dispatch($request);
    }
}
```

Add.php -- (Index controller add action)

```
<?php

namespace Companyname\Faq\Controller\Index;

class Add extends \Companyname\Faq\Controller\Index {
    public function execute() {
    try {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();               

        $faq = $this->_objectManager->create('Companyname\Faq\Model\Faq');
        $faq->setData($params);     
        $faq->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Companyname\Faq\Model\Faq.php

```
namespace Companyname\Faq\Model;

class Faq extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {
    public function __construct() {
    $this->_init('Companyname\Faq\Model\Resource\Faq');
    }
}
```

Companyname\Faq\Model\Resource\Faq.php

```
namespace Companyname\Faq\Model\Resource;

class Faq extends \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb {
    protected function _construct() {
    $this->_init('faq', 'faq_id');
    }
}
```

i get post data properly and the model also loads correctly with this line - `$this->_objectManager->create('Companyname\Faq\Model\Faq');`

However, when it tries to save the data, an error gets generated. **Fatal error: Call to a member function dispatch() on a non-object in \lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel.php on line 663**

After a little debugging, i found that it is not getting eventManager inside  \lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel.php in this line -  `$this->_eventManager->dispatch('model_load_before', $params);`

Any clues as to what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Looks like problem in `Companyname\Faq\Model\Faq` model. Can you show it?

Comment: @KAndy - i have updated the question to include Companyname\Faq\Model\Faq model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem in method `__construct`. You need to call **_**construct (one underlinen), not **__**construct, like

```
namespace Companyname\Faq\Model;

class Faq extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {
    public function _construct() {
           $this->_init('Companyname\Faq\Model\Resource\Faq');
    }
}
```

I think we need to have better name for this "pseudo constructor" method

Comment: Do you clear cache and var/generation dirs? Still the same exception?

Comment: in addition to ur solution i had passed the table name wrong. thanks anyway for the help